# Having issues in takeCommand() in VS Code and PyCharm

Tags: python

```py
if __name__=="__main__" :
    wishme()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
```

takeCommand is not defined. Can anyone help me?
Having this Issue:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\Jarvis\Jarvis.py", line 66, in <module>
    query = takeCommand().lower()
NameError: name 'takeCommand' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query = takeCommand().lower()
```

Above line suggests that `takeCommand()` is some function which should return some string and then you are converting that string in lower case.

Can you please verify that

1. your function `takeCommand()` exists and
2. it returns a **string** value.

Seems like it has to do nothing with VSCode or PyCharm IDE

Comment: So what I have to do to make this code work I am just making JARVIS from a youtube tutorial in which the youtube use takeCommand() with no error but I am having the issues

Comment: Well for that, you need to understand your requirement clearly. Try posting the full code if you have. This is just incomplete code. 
In video tutorials, tutor sometimes don't show the full code.